# Difference in Logoff notification events between Windows XP and Windows 7

Tags: c, winapi, events, session, service

I have a service / application which receives notifications of Windows session changes.
I have noted a difference in behaviour between Windows XP and Windows 7 and am trying to establish if it is a bug or a documented change of behaviour.

The notifications come in as a: `WTSSESSION_NOTIFICATION`.

Windows XP reports as expected: `WTS_SESSION_LOGON` at windows GUI logon and: `WTS_SESSION_LOGOFF` at Windows GUI logoff.

Under Windows 7 x64 at gui login `WTS_SESSION_LOGON` is generated but at logoff I get a `WTS_CONSOLE_DISCONNECT` event instead of the `WTS_SESSION_LOGOFF` event.

Is this a bug or have the constant values changed between versions? It is not massively critical for the service I have developed but I would still like to know why this behaves differently.

Comment: WTS_CONSOLE_DISCONNECT event instead of the WTS_CONSOLE_DISCONNECT?

Comment: Constant values didn't change, WTS_CONSOLE_DISCONNECT was defined for XP (according to a quick google search). Is the LOGOFF event totally missing? Maybe Win7 just disconnects the session before Logoff?

Comment: Are you using `WTSRegisterSessionNotification` or `RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx`?  Because of session isolation, I wouldn't expect the former to work for a service on Vista or Windows 7.

Comment: @Adrian: You could have more than one session pre Vista. WTSRegisterSessionNotification is for things that have HWND's and a service usually does not. (I did not test, but I would expect that WTSRegisterSessionNotification with the all flag will get every notification on NT6 also)

Comment: @Anders: I know services usually don't have a window.  But in XP they *could* have a window, and in Vista+ they cannot because they are run in a non-interactive session.  If the service was originally designed for XP and depends on a window, then that would explain the problem.

Comment: @Adrian: NT6 services can have windows, there is even a global hook that checks for stupid services with windows. But yes, services are generally console programs and not GUI programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only services can receive the WTS_SESSION_LOGOFF event under Windows 7. By the time that the service gets the notification the log off procedure is over (so all apps the user was running are already killed).

Comment: Re: (WTS_CONSOLE_DISCONNECT event instead of the WTS_CONSOLE_DISCONNECT?) That was a mistake and I have edited the question so it is worded correctly now.

Comment: The code in question is actually a service. It is supposed to run independent of any given login session and is in fact supposed to keep track of who logs in and out in order to build and activity log. As this is the first native service I have written I might have done something wrong regarding its behaviour, if it only starts during a login session then it is working wrong. The thing I find wierd is that it is only Windows 7 which gives the console disconnect event instead of session logoff. Windows Vista gives a session logoff like XP, I find that more surprising.

Comment: As all this service needs to do is track that someone has logged in and logged out. The fact that a different event than expected is being fired is more of an annoyance than anything. As I can't find any documentation stating that the behaviour is supposed to have changed I don't know if it is simply a bug in Windows 7. Before contacting Microsoft about this I wanted to sanity check whether this is really likely to be a bug or at very least undocumented change in behaviour before I contact Microsoft to spare me looking foolish (or at least more so than usual).

Comment: @Carl Which account is your service running under?
Does it appears in the services.msc list?